# Regression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

Trying to do logistic regression through pandas and statsmodels.  Don't know why I'm getting an error or how to fix it.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
x = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8]
y = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
d = { "x": pd.Series(x), "y": pd.Series(y)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

model = "y ~ x"
glm = sm.Logit(model, df=df).fit()
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regress.py", line 45, in <module>
    glm = sm.Logit(model, df=df).fit()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't pass a formula to `Logit`. Do:

```
In [82]: import patsy

In [83]: f = 'y ~ x'

In [84]: y, X = patsy.dmatrices(f, df, return_type='dataframe')

In [85]: sm.Logit(y, X).fit().summary()
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.511631
         Iterations 6
Out[85]:
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                           Logit Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                    5
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                        3
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            1
Date:                Fri, 30 Aug 2013   Pseudo R-squ.:                  0.2398
Time:                        16:56:38   Log-Likelihood:                -2.5582
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -3.3651
                                        LLR p-value:                    0.2040
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     -2.0544      2.452     -0.838      0.402        -6.861     2.752
x              0.5672      0.528      1.073      0.283        -0.468     1.603
==============================================================================
"""
```

This is pretty much straight from [the docs on how to do exactly what you're asking](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html#using-formulas-with-models-that-do-not-yet-support-them).

**EDIT:** You can also use the formula API, as suggested by @user333700:

```
In [22]: print sm.formula.logit(model, data=df).fit().summary()
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.511631
         Iterations 6
                           Logit Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                    5
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                        3
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            1
Date:                Fri, 30 Aug 2013   Pseudo R-squ.:                  0.2398
Time:                        18:14:26   Log-Likelihood:                -2.5582
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -3.3651
                                        LLR p-value:                    0.2040
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     -2.0544      2.452     -0.838      0.402        -6.861     2.752
x              0.5672      0.528      1.073      0.283        -0.468     1.603
==============================================================================
```

Comment: or use formula function `import statsmodels.api as smf` and then smf.logit(formula, ...)

Comment: Thanks Phillip for providing a corrected answer. My comment was to fast. I wanted to write `import statsmodels.formula.api as smf` which also gives access to shortcut, lowercase functions for the formula interface. Those are just convenience wrappers around the `from_formula` methods of the models, for example `sm.Logit.from_formula`

Comment: How do i define the reference category? This don't work:             f = 'C(y,Treatment(0)) ~ x '

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a formula directly in Logit too.

```
Logit.from_formula('y ~ x',data=data).fit()
```